# php explode is hitting maximum size

Tags: php, explode

I have a script which gathers information from a linux command and then splits the string into an array

Problem is once the command gathers loads of lines the explode function just stops working

```
$fetch = shell_exec('BIGLISTOFNEWLINESPERATEDDATA');

$fetcharray = explode("\n", $fetch);
```

I have also tried-

`$fetcharray = explode("\n", $fetch,-1);`

and

`$fetcharray = preg_split("\n", $fetch);`

But they all have the same issue - I know that the string command itself is fine because I can output it as a string no matter what the length...

Comment: Say you exploded, what are the next  steps?

Comment: It's unclear what "stops working" means exactly? Do you get an error?

Comment: the page doesn't render anything after the line that contains the explode command - it just stops dead

Comment: FYI: IT works with approx 590402 values, ( i cant get the exact figure)

Comment: Might be a case of a loop, find the next new line and extract the first part, repeat until all of the string is processed.

Comment: The next steps are that it runs though the array of values and manipulates the data into a different format and then feeds them back into another command + outputs a selection of the values into a html table

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, php was hitting its maximum memory size.

I upped that in `php.ini` and now it can reder much more data.