# PHP Explode maximum length string

Tags: php, string, variables, explode, memory-limit

I'm writing a code which splits the text with the explode function, and usually it works well. This is what it does:

> There's a text with some embed questions like this one: "Hey
> {simple|name|What's your name?|Please write your full name}, thanks
> for reading!" in the middle of a paragraph, and that's interpreted in
> order to create contracts and stuff.

[Here's an screenshot of this code working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0Anc.png)

Everything works fine until at real life users put really long texts and the explode function explodes and stop working. This is an example of this long texts:

> {binary|Obligacion_EHS| ¿El contrato requiere el cumplimiento de
> obligaciones de Seguridad Ambiental?| Si selecciona que sí, el
> contrato contendrá la cláusula de obligaciones en materia ambiental|
> Que cumple con las disposiciones aplicables en materia de seguridad,
> salud y medio ambiente en el trabajo, respecto de sus trabajadores,
> incluyendo sin limitar los lineamientos internos que se agregan al
> presente Contrato como Anexo 5A, y que sus filiales y/o sus
> proveedores que participen en la ejecución de los Servicios
> Especializados también las cumplen. Derivado de lo anterior, EL
> CONTRATISTA deberá presentar a SIEMENS ENERGY los siguientes
> documentos: a. Certificado OHSAS 18001 vigente. b. El registro vigente
> de sus filiales y/o sus proveedores en el Padrón Público de
> Contratistas de Servicios Especializados u Obras Especializadas ante
> la Secretaría del Trabajo y Previsión Social, con sus datos
> correspondientes consistentes en: Números ********** y fechas
> ************ y que contenga los Servicios Especializados que le proporcionarán a EL CONTRATISTA. c. Cualquier documento que a
> satisfacción de SIEMENS ENERGY demuestre que EL CONTRATISTA cumple con
> el marco normativo Local y Federal en la República Mexicana de
> seguridad y salud en el trabajo. d. Certificado de Industria Segura -
> Programa de Autogestión STPS vigente. e. Acreditación reciente (1 año
> máximo) que EL CONTRATISTA cumple con los requerimientos en materia de
> seguridad, salud y medio ambiente, emitido por un auditor externo
> donde se valide que: i. EL CONTRATISTA da cumplimiento a los
> requerimientos legales aplicables en materia de seguridad, salud y
> medio ambiente. ii. Sus trabajadores cuentan con las competencias de
> seguridad adecuadas para los servicios especializados que EL
> CONTRATISTA presta realiza. iii. Sus trabajadores cuentan con las
> certificaciones de competencias laborales, las certificaciones
> oficiales o conforme a las leyes con las constancias de capacitación y
> adiestramiento necesarias para los servicios especializados que EL
> CONTRATISTA iv. EL CONTRATISTA cuenta con un proceso efectivo para el
> control del riesgo de sus actividades. En caso de incumplimiento de
> cualquiera de las obligaciones establecidas en el presente inciso,
> SIEMENS ENERGY, sin perjuicio de cualquier otro derecho contenido en
> el presente Contrato, podrá aplicar a EL CONTRATISTA una penalización
> del 10% (diez por ciento) del valor total de la Orden de Compra
> correspondiente.}

The idea is that I have 6 different "input types":

- Simple, which is a simple question
- Binary, which print a radio button (yes/no) question that if you press "yes" you get the policy applied if you said yes.
- Multiple, which is a select list with options.
- Monetary, which transform quantities to text amounts.
- Date, which shows a date picker.
- Repeater, which copies the value of any of the previous ones.

What I usually do is first get all the "embed" questions in the "content" into the matches variable:

```
// Check for variables within this template file.
preg_match_all('/{(.*)}/U', $content, $matches);
```

And then I create html elements with those embed questions in the matches variable like this:

```
// Found matches.
echo '<br><br><p><strong>New Dynamic Form Generated</strong></p>';
foreach ($matches[0] as $id => $match) {
   $rep = $matches[1][$id];
   $generator = explode('|', $rep);
   echo '<p>'.$generator[2].' <span class="tooltip tooltip-txt" data-tooltip="'.$generator[1].'"><i class="icon-info-circled"></i></span></p>';
   echo '<input type="text" class="newremplace" name="'.trim($generator[1]).'_in" id="'.trim($generator[3]).'_in" ><br>';
  }
echo '<input type="button" id="reemplazar" value="Remplace"><br><br>';
```

But as I already mention, when I used the long long "variable embed" it just don't work,

I found this question [php explode is hitting maximum size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66787236/php-explode-is-hitting-maximum-size) and I tried changing the memory_limit in my php.ini from 128M to 512M, and I restarted the server, but the problem remains the same.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

I change the test content to this one:

> CONSIDERANDO QUE, {simple| Representante1_SE | ¿Cuál es el nombre del
> primer Representante de SE?| Por política los contratos deben ser
> firmados por 2 representantes} y {simple| Representante2_SE | ¿Cuál es
> el nombre del Segundo Representante de SE?| Por política los contratos
> deben ser firmados por 2 representantes} actuando en este acto como
> representantes legales de SIEMENS ENERGY, tienen las facultades
> legales suficientes para firmar el presente Contrato, en nombre y
> representación de SIEMENS ENERGY, las cuales no les han sido
> modificadas o limitadas en forma alguna, como consta en la copia del
> documento integrado como Anexo 4 del presente Contrato.
> {binaria|Obligacion_EHS| ¿El contrato requiere el cumplimiento de
> obligaciones de Seguridad Ambiental?| Si selecciona que sí, el
> contrato contendrá la cláusula de obligaciones en materia ambiental|
> Que cumple con las disposiciones aplicables en materia de seguridad,
> salud y medio ambiente en el trabajo, respecto de sus trabajadores,
> incluyendo sin limitar los lineamientos internos que se agregan al
> presente Contrato como Anexo 5A, y que sus filiales y/o sus
> proveedores que participen en la ejecución de los Servicios
> Especializados también las cumplen. Derivado de lo anterior, EL
> CONTRATISTA deberá presentar a SIEMENS ENERGY los siguientes
> documentos: a. Certificado OHSAS 18001 vigente. b. El registro vigente
> de sus filiales y/o sus proveedores en el Padrón Público de
> Contratistas de Servicios Especializados u Obras Especializadas ante
> la Secretaría del Trabajo y Previsión Social, con sus datos
> correspondientes consistentes en: Números ********** y fechas
> ************ y que contenga los Servicios Especializados que le proporcionarán a EL CONTRATISTA. c. Cualquier documento que a
> satisfacción de SIEMENS ENERGY demuestre que EL CONTRATISTA cumple con
> el marco normativo Local y Federal en la República Mexicana de
> seguridad y salud en el trabajo. d. Certificado de Industria Segura -
> Programa de Autogestión STPS vigente. e. Acreditación reciente (1 año
> máximo) que EL CONTRATISTA cumple con los requerimientos en materia de
> seguridad, salud y medio ambiente, emitido por un auditor externo
> donde se valide que: i. EL CONTRATISTA da cumplimiento a los
> requerimientos legales aplicables en materia de seguridad, salud y
> medio ambiente. ii. Sus trabajadores cuentan con las competencias de
> seguridad adecuadas para los servicios especializados que EL
> CONTRATISTA presta realiza. iii. Sus trabajadores cuentan con las
> certificaciones de competencias laborales, las certificaciones
> oficiales o conforme a las leyes con las constancias de capacitación y
> adiestramiento necesarias para los servicios especializados que EL
> CONTRATISTA iv. EL CONTRATISTA cuenta con un proceso efectivo para el
> control del riesgo de sus actividades. En caso de incumplimiento de
> cualquiera de las obligaciones establecidas en el presente inciso,
> SIEMENS ENERGY, sin perjuicio de cualquier otro derecho contenido en
> el presente Contrato, podrá aplicar a EL CONTRATISTA una penalización
> del 10% (diez por ciento) del valor total de la Orden de Compra
> correspondiente.} CONSIDERANDO QUE, SIEMENS ENERGY requiere Contratar
> y recibir los Servicios Especializados (según dicho término se define
> más adelante) de EL CONTRATISTA, bajo los términos y condiciones
> estipulados en el presente Contrato. CONSIDERANDO QUE, EL CONTRATISTA
> es una sociedad debidamente constituida conforme a las leyes
> mexicanas, cuyo domicilio fiscal está ubicado en {simple|
> Registro_Patronal_Proveedores| ¿Cuál es el Número de Registro Patronal
> del Proveedor?| Es el número que otorga el IMSS a todas las Empresas
> para el registro de sus trabajadores}, como consta en la copia de la
> escritura constitutiva integrada como Anexo 4 del presente Contrato y
> cuenta con el Número de Registro Patronal {simple|
> Registro_Patronal_Proveedor| ¿Cuál es el Número de Registro Patronal
> del Proveedor?| Es el número que otorga el IMSS a todas las Empresas
> para el registro de sus trabajadores}

And this is the code that I'm using:

```
echo '<h3><strong>Text to process</strong></h3><pre>';
    var_dump($content);
    echo '</pre>';

    // Check for variables within this template file.
    preg_match_all('/{(.*)}/U', $content, $matches);

    echo '<h3><strong>Found variables</strong></h3><pre>';
    print_r($matches[0]);
    echo '</pre>';


    // Found matches.  $matches[0] has the {}, $matches[1] doesn't have the {}
    echo '<br><br><h3><strong>New Dynamic Form Generated</strong></h3><br>';
    foreach ($matches[0] as $id => $match) {

        $rep = $matches[1][$id];
        $generator = explode('|', $rep);
        echo '<pre>'; 
        print_r($generator);
        echo '</pre>';
        echo '<p>'.$generator[2].' <span class="tooltip tooltip-txt" data-tooltip="'.$generator[3].'"><i class="icon-info-circled"></i></span></p>';
        echo '<input type="text" class="newremplace" name="'.trim($generator[1]).'_in" id="'.trim($generator[1]).'_in" ><br>';
    }
    echo '<input type="button" id="reemplazar" value="Remplace"><br><br>';



    // {nombre_empresa | ¿Cuál es el nombre de la empresa? | Esta, es una socia }
    foreach ($matches[0] as $id => $match) {

        $rep = $matches[1][$id];
        $generator = explode('|', $rep);
        $generator = '<span id="'.trim($generator[0]).'" class="remplace"></span>';
        $content = str_replace($match, $generator, $content);
    }

    echo '<p><strong>Dynamic Content</strong></p><div style="width: 100%; heigth: auto; border: 1px solid #e8e8e8; padding: 15px;">';
    echo $content;
    echo '</div>';
```

So, I found out that explode is not the problem, because when I print the found variables before explode them I just have 4, instead of 5.

```
Array
(
    [0] => {simple| Representante1_SE | ¿Cuál es el nombre del primer Representante de SE?| Por política los contratos deben ser firmados por 2 representantes}
    [1] => {simple| Representante2_SE | ¿Cuál es el nombre del Segundo Representante de SE?| Por política los contratos deben ser firmados por 2 representantes}
    [2] => {simple| Registro_Patronal_Proveedores| ¿Cuál es el Número de Registro Patronal del Proveedor?| Es el número que otorga el IMSS a todas las Empresas para el registro de sus trabajadores}
    [3] => {simple| Registro_Patronal_Proveedor| ¿Cuál es el Número de Registro Patronal del Proveedor?| Es el número que otorga el IMSS a todas las Empresas para el registro de sus trabajadores}
)
```

So I guess the problem is the length that **preg_match_all** can handle so, I research and I found that I can change the value of **pcre.backtrack_limit** for **10485760**, I restarted the Apache but even so, I still have the same issue, I just can see 4 of five variables.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2. (Solved)**

I finally got it! The problem was in my REGEX Function, I just added an **s** modifier and that solve it.

```
preg_match_all('/{(.*)}/sU', $content, $matches);
```

Thank you to everyone who helped me.

Comment: And what makes your question any different than the duplicate you've linked? Besides, changing PHP INI values on a shared hosting might lead exactly nowhere; simply get more RAM to work with.

Comment: @MartinZeitler That I already push the memory_limit = 2048M and I still have no way to make it work, and this is inside my MAMP so, I don't know what else to do. Do you think I should increase more the memory_limit? Don't you think could it be something different like max_input_vars or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum length of a String in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189040/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-string-in-php) (which is quite an exact duplicate)... try `ini_set()` and `ini_get()` to see if it even applied the value (assuming the machine has enough physical RAM).

Comment: That example text isn't long enough to exceed any likely memory limit.

Comment: It works fine here: https://ideone.com/cYN1is

Comment: @MartinZeitler well I just saw your question and yes I can see with a php info that I already have set my  memory_limit | 2048M | 2048M but I think that's not even needed because my text is not that long.

Comment: @Barmar I saw the link and as you mention, it works... But why here at my MAMP/MacOS is not working? Is it the RAM, the max_input_vars, the max_execution_time?

Comment: No idea, as you haven't provided any details of the failure. Are you getting any errors in the log that suggest exceeding a limit?

Comment: Can confirm it seems to work fine: https://3v4l.org/nb76k#v7.4.27 What exactly do you mean by "*is not working*"?  If you add some debugging (like `print_r()` etc), does it look OK?

Comment: @Barmar No logs, no errors, nothing. For example if I use more instructions like that one such as: {simple|var_1|text|text|text} {simple| var_2 |text|text|text} {binary|THE_LONG_ONE|text|text|text} {simple| var_3 |text|text|text} {simple| var_4 |text|text|text}, the code execute the vars_1 to var_4 and ignores the long one, with no errors or warnings, nothing.

Comment: @Don'tPanic here's a link of my testing site (it's a DigitalOcean hosting) I preload the variable content with 5 different instructions 4 simples and the long one, I can't find why is just like skipping the log one... https://clientes.portafolioweb.pro/hublegal/test-parsing-data/

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what I'm looking at on your test site.  [In the example I set up (updated with more info output)](https://3v4l.org/A80bo#v7.4.27), does the problem show up? Can you edit that example, and make the error show up?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I modified your code to show the error... https://3v4l.org/lY0lN#v7.4.27 Take a look, now there's 5 different "instructions" between the curly brackets but you just can see 4, because in the middle I insert the long one. That's the one that is not working.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I found the error I just have to add the "s" modifier to my regex sentence because my text has break lines so, thank you anyway.